# Trying to produce function for a custom number of tkinter Entry fields.

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to create a piece of code that would take a integer as a argument and create that number of tkinter entry fields. With a submit button at the end that would retrieve the data from the fields add these data to a list then close the window.

I have been able to get it working however I cant find a way to convert this to a callable function; a requirement to use it with the rest of my program. 
This is the code I have produced so far, thanks:

```
import tkinter as tk

b = input("Enter: ")
b = int(b)

root = tk.Tk()

newdict = dict()

outputs = list()

for i in range(b):
    newdict["entry" + str(i)] = tk.Entry(root)
    newdict["entry" + str(i)].pack()

button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=lambda: Get(newdict))
button1.pack()

def Get(newdict):
    for j in range(b):
        outputs.append(newdict["entry" + str(j)].get())
        root.quit()

root.mainloop()

print(outputs)
```

Comment: What exactly is the difficulty you are having?

Comment: Do you want the whole program (including the creation of the root window) as a single function?

Comment: I can't just add a return to to my code so to make it a function as it returns an empty list.

Comment: Well as I want to be able to call this at several times in my program, yes create a new window each time it is called. But I could just put the window initialization around the function call.

Comment: Is this the only GUI you use, or is it in addition to an existing GUI? You'll need to use something like [TopLevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) if it is in addition to existing GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to create a window, then use the `wait_window` method to wait for the window to be destroyed. Once it has been destroyed you can return some value.

The problem is that the values you want to fetch must not be attributes of the window, since it will have been destroyed by the time you are ready to fetch them. You need to set up your code to save the values before the window is destroyed.

A simple way is to provide an "OK" button which gets the values and then destroys the window. Another way would be to put a trace on variables associated with each entry, and save the values immediately as they are edited.

Which method you choose depends on what behavior you want when the user clicks the window control to close the window (eg: the red circle on OSX, the [x] button on windows, etc). Do you want to return what they had input, or do you treat that as a cancel action and return nothing?

Here's a simple example using an OK button. This example assumes that you aren't already running a GUI, and that this is to be run as part of a non-GUI application.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Dialog(object):
    def show(self, num_fields):
        self.num_fields = num_fields
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.entries = []
        for i in range(num_fields):
            entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
            entry.pack(fill="x")
            self.entries.append(entry)

        ok = tk.Button(self.root, text="OK", command=self.ok)
        ok.pack(side="bottom", anchor="e", pady=(10,0), padx=10)

        # wait for the window to be destroyed, then
        # return the values. If the user clicks the OK button
        # the values will be set; if they cancel the dialog
        # this will return None.
        self.values = None
        self.root.wait_window()
        return self.values

    def ok(self):
        # save all the values, then destroy the window
        self.values = []
        for i in range(self.num_fields):
            self.values.append(self.entries[i].get())

        self.root.destroy()
```

Assuming you're running a non-gui program, here's an example of how you would use this class:

```
b = input("Enter: ")
b = int(b)
result = Dialog().show(b)
print("result:", result)
```

Comment: Thanks this is absolutely perfect. Wish I had known about wait_window() before starting to write my program. It would have been very useful. Now I can tidy up the rest of the code.